# Text view is not adjusting according to weights in linear layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

This is my xml file to design a layout. I am using liner layout with weights to set the layout. but text view with id data_message and its follower layout is not taking weight according to given. all other layout before it working proper.
I can't understand this error. please help to find out this.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:weightSum="100"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:background="@color/primary_dark_material_dark"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">
    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:src="@drawable/logoback"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/home_img"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userbox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4.5"
        android:textColor="#ffffff">

    </TextView>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/optionmenu"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:prompt="@string/profile"
        android:tag="Menu"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        ></Spinner>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="90"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/name"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/company_name"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data_company"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/saddress"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data_address"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/phone"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data_phnNo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/subject"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data_sub"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/city"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data_city"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data_message"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:hint="Message"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_dark_material_dark"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/canrplybtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/rply"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark_material_dark"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/form"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: data_message is not wrapped around any `LinearLayout` , either put it in above or below `LinearLayout`. And also the below `LinearLayout` seems to be useless since it has no child.

Comment: Can you show some mock up what exactly you are trying to build?

Comment: Have you tried to remove android:minHeight?

Comment: you are trying to use `weight` having a `ScrollView`  as parent you might not get desire result and a tip please do not use `nested weight` you can face performance issue

Comment: @SharpEdge i thing wrapping is not a problem because the LinearLayout below the text view is also not taking the weight ratio properly.

Answer (score 1):

remove

```
android:minHeight="50dp"
```

Comment: what should i do for layouts below the textview because they are also not taking weight according to given.

Comment: all are having same weight , and i think all are looking same in graphical layout

Answer (score 0):

Update your layout code with following:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark_material_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10">
        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:src="@drawable/logoback"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/home_img"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userbox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4.5"
            android:textColor="#ffffff">

        </TextView>
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/optionmenu"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:prompt="@string/profile"
            android:tag="Menu"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            ></Spinner>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="90"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_margin="2dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/name"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/data_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_margin="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/company_name"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/data_company"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_margin="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/saddress"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/data_address"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_margin="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/phone"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/data_phnNo"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_margin="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/subject"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/data_sub"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_margin="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/city"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/data_city"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_margin="2dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data_message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:hint="Message"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_dark_material_dark"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">
            </LinearLayout>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/canrplybtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/rply"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:background="@color/primary_dark_material_dark"
                android:textColor="@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/form"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you changed?

Comment: I have put your data_message text view inside a linear layout :-

Comment: but its not working after the put data_messsage text view inside a liner layout.

Answer (score 0):

The direct child of a ScrollView should have the height set to `wrap_content`. If you want a fill screen effect, you can set `android::fillViewport="true"` on the ScrollView.

If you do this, you will start noticing that all the ratios are going to be as desired.